# ¿De que manera se puede imprimir una cadena de texto en c++ usando solo iostream, char?

Tags: c++

He pasado horas buscando en internet sobre como imprimir cadena de texto con espacios en c++, pero no he podido usando cin.getline(texto,100), aqui esta mi codigo. Creo que se puede usar string, pero no se si lo permiten, también he leído que es más eficiente usar char, cuales serían las posibles soluciones a este problema, ya lo han experimentado?

```
/*programa de venta de zapatos
hecho por juan araujo
usando emacs editor
en gnu / linux os

*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  int referencia;
  int talla;
  char disponibilidad[2];
  float costo, precio;
  char descripcion[100];

  cout << "Administrar Venta de Zapatos" << endl;

  cout << "Digite la referencia del zapato..." << endl;
  cin >> referencia;

  //imprimir peticion
  cout << "Digite una descripción del zapato..." << endl;

  //leer descripcion
  cin.getline(descripcion,100);

  cout << "Digita la talla..." << endl;
  cin >> talla;

  cout << "Digita la letra si esta disponible o no para la venta S/N..." << endl;
  cin >> disponibilidad;

  cout << "Digita el costo del zapato..." << endl;
  cin >> costo;

  cout << "Digita el precio de venta del zapato..." << endl;
  cin >> precio;


  cout << "Los Datos Registrados son los siguientes" << endl;

  cout << "Referencia: " << referencia  << endl;

  //imprimir descripcion
  cout << "Descripción: " << descripcion  << endl;
  cout << "Talla: " << talla  << endl;
  cout << "Disponibilidad: " << disponibilidad  << endl;
  cout << "Costo: " << costo  << endl;
  cout << "Precio: " << precio  << endl;

  cout << " " << endl;
  cout << "¡Gracias por digitar la información!" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto;

```
char string[100];
printf("Ingresa una cadena, no importa si tiene espacios:\n");
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string);
printf ("Ha ingresado: %s", string);
return 0;
```

O en caso contrario intenta con lo siguiente;

```
char string[100]
cin.getline(string, sizeof(string));
```

Comment: no realiza la petición del dato de entrada, cuando escribo la opción de caso contrario, voy a intentar la primera opción.

Comment: en char string[100] puedo cambiar string por otro nombre como "descripcion"

Comment: Si, puedes utilizar el nombre que quieras. Perdón, string es el nombre de la variable.